# Is there a better method of determining if an integer ends in specific two digits?

Tags: sql, sqlite

In a table having an integer primary key of `indexRow` in which the last two digits are currently 55, I'd like to change that to 50 but only if the column `added` is an integer value 55 and the `indexRow` ends in 55. I'm using SQLite.

I tested it as follows. Would you please tell me if this is the correct approach (if there is a better method) because I'd like to use it to run an update on the table?

Of course, I'll do it within a transaction and test before committing; but wanted to ask. I expected to have to use some math to determine which indexRows ended in 55, but converting to string seems quite easy.

```
select indexRow, indexRow-5, substring(format('%s', indexRow),-2)
from newSL
where added=55
  and substring(format('%s', indexRow),-2)='55'
limit 10;
indexRow     indexRow-5   substring(format('%s', indexRow),-2)
-----------  -----------  ------------------------------------
10080171455  10080171450  55                                  
10130031255  10130031250  55                                  
10140021655  10140021650  55                                  
10140080955  10140080950  55                                  
10240330155  10240330150  55                                  
10250230555  10250230550  55                                  
10270031155  10270031150  55                                  
10270290355  10270290350  55                                  
10300110355  10300110350  55                                  
10300110455  10300110450  55
```

Comment: A simple `SUBSTR(indexRow, -2)` works for any data type in SQLite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use the modulo operator, `%`. In the expression `x % y`, the result is the remainder of dividing `x` by `y`.  Therefore, 4173 % 100 = 73.

Note that `%` is a math operator, just like * for multiplication and / for division, and is not related to using the `%` in the format function.